# jQuery: nextAll independent of parents

Tags: jquery

I'm building a small lightbox-plugin (just for fun) and if the user presses a key, it should open (simulate click) the next link having the same "rel"-attribute.

```
 .nextAll('.box[rel="'+boxed+'"]').eq(0).click();
```

The code above works for the following example:

```
<a href="/1.jpg" class="box" rel="box-abc123">One</a>
<a href="/2.jpg" class="box" rel="box-abc123">Two</a>
<a href="/3.jpg" class="box" rel="box-abc123">Three</a>
```

But if the images are in different parent-elements, like…

```
<header><a href="/1.jpg" class="box" rel="box-abc123">One</a></header>
<section><a href="/2.jpg" class="box" rel="box-abc123">Two</a></section>
<footer><a href="/3.jpg" class="box" rel="box-abc123">Three</a></footer>
```

…it doesn't work. Of course I could use parent() to jump, but I want to build it completely independent of parent-elements (as there aren't some always). Is there a way to find the next element independent of any parent-elements? Does anybody know how to solve this? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you don't want to use parent element the use `slice` to get next all elements

```
$('a.box[rel="'+boxed+'"]').slice($('a.box[rel="'+boxed+'"]').index(this))
```

working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/aaWHt/2/

Comment: Slight bug in that you're selecting on `a.box[rel=....]` but then indexing only on `a`, so you get incorrect results if you have any `a` tags that aren't `[rel=...]` on the page

Comment: The index()-thing helped me out – now everything works as I wanted. Thank you very much! :)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem to this - basically trying to get the next element in a set regardless of where they appear in the dom tree. The best solution was to loop over these elements initially, and give them an `id`, which could then be used to select the next element.

```
$boxSelector = $('.box[rel="box-abc123"]');

$boxSelector.each(function(i, v) {
  $(this).prop('id', 'box-' + ++i);
});
```

You can then get the `id` of the next `.box` by doing something similar to this:

```
var nextId = '';
var boxLength = $boxSelector.length;

$boxSelector.on('click', function() {
  var thisIndex = parseInt(this.id.replace(/[^\d]+/, ''));
  nextId = (thisIndex == boxLength) ? 1 : thisIndex+1;
});
```

You can then select the next element using:

```
$('#box-' + nextId);
```

I understand that this doesn't directly answer your question, but you should be able to apply the same principles to achieve the desired result.

Comment: Unfortunately some of the boxes already have an ID, so I can't overwrite them. Therefore I decided to use the tip above. Nevertheless, it's a great tip – so thank you very much for it! :)